# Taking the alternate value from tuple

Tags: python, data-structures

How to take the other(unmatched value) from tuple?

For example: I have `val = 'y'`

and `t = ('y', 'n')`

I want to return `'n'` from the tuple. Something like

```
if val=='y':
   return 'n'
else:
   retun 'y'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following statement:

```
return t[0] if val == 'y' else t[1]
```

You can also index into a tuple:

```
return t[val == 'n']
```

Comment: Indexing the tuple seems much more pythonic.

Comment: @desertSniper87, I definitely agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that True==1 and False==0:

```
t = ('y', 'n')

def other(t, val):
    return t[t[0]==val]

print(other(t, 'y'))
print(other(t, 'n'))
# n
# y
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack the tuple's data and use a condition:

```
# if there is 2 elements in your tuple
# Otherwise:
# a, b, *c = ('n', 'y', 'c', ...)
a, b = ('n', 'y')
return a if a == 'y' else b
```

Answer (score 0):

Another good solution is to use a dictionary:

```
d={'y':t[0]}
return d.get(val,t[1])
```

Output:

```
y
```